# How to fix the following text in text file using regex?

Tags: python, string

I want to copy a lot of text from a text file without having to manually sit and edit said file for hours on end, so how would I go about removing all unwanted characters in the following example using python's re library?

```
    ""Bourgogne-ComtE_"",  "}
    ""l_Aigle"",  "}
    ""Flotte"",  "}
    ""Vendome"",  "}
    ""Champagne"",  "}
    ""Namur"",  "}
    ""Bissy"",  "}
    ""Eu"",  "}
    ""Perche"",  "}
```

Here's how I want the text to look:

```
"Bourgogne-ComtE",
"l_Aigle",
"Flotte",
"Vendome",
"Champagne",
"Namur",
"Bissy",
"Eu",
"Perche",
```

So I want to remove the whitespace before the words, then I want to remove the first double quotes, then any line at the end of the word, then the last double quote and finally the double quote with the curly brace at the end.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Is the `_` a typo or also supposed to be removed?

Comment: It's should also be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one way to do so:

```
import re

text = """
    ""Bourgogne-ComtE_"",  "}
    ""l_Aigle"",  "}
    ""Flotte"",  "}
    ""Vendome"",  "}
    ""Champagne"",  "}
    ""Namur"",  "}
    ""Bissy"",  "}
    ""Eu"",  "}
    ""Perche"",  "}
"""

text = re.sub(r'\s{4}"(.*?)",\s{2}"}', r'\1,', text)

print(text)
```

---

**Output:**

```
"Bourgogne-ComtE_",
"l_Aigle",
"Flotte",
"Vendome",
"Champagne",
"Namur",
"Bissy",
"Eu",
"Perche",
```

See [here](https://regex101.com/r/1u7nSz/1) for the demo.

---

- `\s{4}`: Matches 4 white spaces.
- `"`: Matches `"`.
- `(.*?)`: Matches any characters between 0 and unlimited times, as few as possible.
- `",`: Matches `",`
- `\s{2}`: Matches 2 white spaces.
- `"}`: Matches `"}`.
- `\1,`: Replaces the match with the first group (`.*?`) and a comma.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this fixed my code and is quite insightful.